# Question about tensor objectivity in continuum mechanics

Tags: tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics

I have a question about tensor objectivity. The Cauchy stress tensor is objective but its time derivative is not. However, tensors are coordinate invariant. Wouldn’t that make all tensors objective by definition?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when two observers are in constant relative position (i.e. one observer doesn't move w.r.t. another), the concept of a vector/tensor to be invariant and objective coincides.

As an example, we can write a vector in two different Cartesian bases as $\mathbf{w} = w^I_i \mathbf{\hat{e}_i}^I = w^J_j \mathbf{\hat{e}_j}^J$, where the following relations between the base vectors hold

$\mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j = \underbrace{\mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j \cdot \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i}_{Q_{ij}} \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i = Q_{ij} \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i$,

and thus, $\mathbf{w} = w^I_i \mathbf{\hat{e}_i}^I = w^J_j \mathbf{\hat{e}_j}^J = w^J_j Q_{ij} \mathbf{\hat{e}_i}^I$ and the relation between the components reads

$w^I_i = w^J_j Q_{ij} $,

that can be written as $\underline{w}^I = \underline{\underline{Q}} \underline{w}^J$, having collected the Cartesian components of the vectors in column vectors $\underline{w}^x$, related by a rotation matrix $\underline{\underline{Q}}$, corresponding to a rotation of the reference frames, that is the condition of **objectivity for the vector**.

When the two observers are in relative motion, relative kinematics provide us with the formulas for the description of kinematic variables as seen by the two observers. As an example, for the velocity of a point $P$ the two descriptions differ by the relative linear motion of the observers and the rotation of the vector bases. To be more clear:

- the following relation holds between the **position** of the point $P$ and the position of the origins of the reference frames

  $(P-O_I) = (P - O_J) + (O_J - O_I)$,

  being $\mathbf{r}_{AB} = (B - A)$ the vector from $A$ to $B$. Each of these vectors can be written in the Cartesian reference frame $I$ with bases $\{\mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i\}_{i=1:3}$ or n the Cartesian reference frame $J$ with bases $\{\mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j\}_{j=1:3}$
- now let's focus on the **velocity** as seen by the two observers, with the same scale of time. The observer $I$ sees the velocity of $P$ as the time derivative of the position

  $\mathbf{v}_{P/O_I}^I := \dot{\mathbf{r}}_{O_I P} = \dot{\mathbf{r}}_{O_I O_J} + \dot{\mathbf{r}}_{P O_J} = \mathbf{v}_{O_J/O_I}^I + \mathbf{v}_{P/O_J}^I$.

  Now, the time derivative of the vector $\mathbf{r}_{P O_J}$ can be written as

  $\dfrac{d \mathbf{r}_{P O_J}}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left( r_{P,j}^J \mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j \right) = \dfrac{d r_{P,j}^J }{dt} \mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j + \mathbf{\Omega}_{J/I} \times \mathbf{r}_{P O_J} = $
  $\qquad \qquad \qquad = v_{P,j}^J \mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j + \mathbf{\Omega}_{J/I} \times \mathbf{r}_{P O_J} = \mathbf{v}_{P / O_J}^J + \mathbf{\Omega}_{J/I} \times \mathbf{r}_{P O_J}$,

  having introduced the definition of the velocity $P$ as seen by the observer $J$,

  $\mathbf{v}_{P / O_J}^J = v_{P,j}^J \mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j = \dfrac{d r_{P,j}^J }{dt} \mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j$

  Putting everything together, the relative kinematics law for the velocity of a point $P$, as seen by two observers $I$ and $J$ in relative motions reads

  $\mathbf{v}_{P/O_I}^I = \mathbf{v}_{O_J / O_I}^I + \mathbf{\Omega}_{J/I} \times \mathbf{r}_{O_J P} + \mathbf{v}^J_{P/O_J}$.

  Now we can write this equation in the base vector of the $I^{th}$ Cartesian reference frame to get

  $v_{P/O_I, i}^I \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i = v_{O_J/O_I, i}^I \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i + \varepsilon_{\ell jk} \Omega^J_j (r^J_{P,k} - r^J_{O_J,k} ) \mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_{\ell} + v_{P/O_J, j}^J \mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j $
  $\qquad \qquad = v_{O_J/O_I, i}^I \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i + \varepsilon_{\ell jk} \Omega^J_j (r^J_{P,k} - r^J_{O_J,k} ) \underbrace{\mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_{\ell}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i}_{Q_{i \ell}} \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i + v_{P/O_J, j}^J \underbrace{\mathbf{\hat{e}}^J_j \cdot \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i}_{Q_{ij}} \mathbf{\hat{e}}^I_i $,

  that can be written collecting the components in vectors and arrays as
  $\underline{v}^I = \underline{\underline{Q}}\underline{v}^J + \underline{\underline{Q}} \underline{\underline{\Omega_{\times}}} \Delta \underline{r} + \underline{v}_{O_J / O_I}^J$

  You can easily realize that the latter condition differs from the objectivity condition $\underline{w}^J = \underline{\underline{Q}}\underline{w}^I$ in general, and the two relations coincide if there is no relative motion, neither linear, $\underline{v}_{O_J / O_I}^J = \underline{0}$, nor rotation, $\underline{\underline{\Omega_{\times}}} = \underline{\underline{0}}$.

For a deeper insight, try to have a look here, sec. 2.8.4.

https://pkel015.connect.amazon.auckland.ac.nz/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_2_Kinematics/Kinematics_of_CM_08_Objectivity.pdf